# How to remove scrollbars from Adobe Animate CC 2015 o0bject

Tags: jquery, css, object, jquery-animate, scrollbars

I want to remove the scroll bars from a simple animation I made.

An example can be found [here](https://www.surfgate.be/ScrollsBeGone/default.html)

**Attempts:**

- I tried CSS `overflow` with no success.
- I even tried the same with the generated html page that Animate made.

My animation has a `1000px` **width** and `290px` **height**.

The one small success is that I set the `height` to `297px` and even then, there is a small grey background on the bottom.

Comment: Removed clutter

Answer (score 0):

Your object tag is calling a

> Top-Main/Assets/Top-Main.html

page. This page has a background color set to **#D4D4D4** remove that and it should work fine

[image]